# Passing two dimensional arrays by reference when calling COM DLL from C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dll, com

I have registered COM DLL and I have reference to it in my C# project in Visual Studio 2012.

I want to call one function from this DLL. It has following signature in documentation:

```
HRESULT CRating(
    [in] BSTR compModelName,
    [in] long refrigCode,
    [in] long powSupCode,
    [in] VARIANT_BOOL tempMidpoint,
    [in] VARIANT_BOOL suctionSGR,
    [in] double suctionRetGasTemp,
    [in] double subcooling,
    [in, out] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT_BOOL)* requiredOutput,
    [in, out] SAFEARRAY(double)* capacity,
    [in, out] SAFEARRAY(double)* power,
    [in, out] SAFEARRAY(double)* current,
    [in, out] SAFEARRAY(double)* massFlow,
    [in, out] SAFEARRAY(double)* heatReject,
    [in, out] SAFEARRAY(long)* errorCode);
```

But when I open it with Object Browser I see following:

```
void CRating(
    string compModelName, 
    int refrigCode, 
    int powSupCode, 
    bool tempMidpoint, 
    bool suctionSGR, 
    double suctionRetGasTemp, 
    double subcooling, 
    ref System.Array requiredOutput, 
    ref System.Array capacity, 
    ref System.Array power, 
    ref System.Array current, 
    ref System.Array massFlow, 
    ref System.Array heatReject, 
    ref System.Array errorCode);
```

`requiredOutput`, `capacity`, `power`, `current`, `massFlow`, `heatReject`, `errorCode` are two dimensional arrays.

Can someone please tell how to call this function from C#?

P.S.: I tried to call this function like this and got `SafeArrayTypeMismatchException`:

```
string compModelName = "ZR40K3E-TFD";
int refrigCode = 4;
int powSupCode = 1;
bool tempMidpoint = false;
bool suctionSGR = false;
double suctionRetGasTemp = 10;
double subcooling = 1;

Array requiredOutput = new bool[] { true, true, true, true, true, true };

Array capacity = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Array), 2);
capacity.SetValue(new double[2] { 0 , 6.4 }, 0);
capacity.SetValue(new double[2] { 50, 0   }, 1);

Array power = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Array), 2);
power.SetValue(new double[2] { 0, 0 }, 0);
power.SetValue(new double[2] { 0, 0 }, 1);

Array current = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Array), 2);
current.SetValue(new double[2] { 0, 0 }, 0);
current.SetValue(new double[2] { 0, 0 }, 1);

Array massFlow = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Array), 2);
massFlow.SetValue(new double[2] { 0, 0 }, 0);
massFlow.SetValue(new double[2] { 0, 0 }, 1);

Array heatReject = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Array), 2);
heatReject.SetValue(new double[2] { 0, 0 }, 0);
heatReject.SetValue(new double[2] { 0, 0 }, 1);

Array errorCode = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Array), 2);
errorCode.SetValue(new int[2] { 0, 0 }, 0);
errorCode.SetValue(new int[2] { 0, 0 }, 1);

KCRate crksrv = new KCRate();
// without ref
crksrv.CRating(compModelName, refrigCode, powSupCode, tempMidpoint, suctionSGR, suctionRetGasTemp, subcooling, requiredOutput, capacity, power, current, massFlow, heatReject, errorCode);
// with ref - same error
crksrv.CRating(compModelName, refrigCode, powSupCode, tempMidpoint, suctionSGR, suctionRetGasTemp, subcooling, ref requiredOutput, ref capacity, ref power, ref current, ref massFlow, ref heatReject, ref errorCode);
```

Comment: You are creating jagged arrays, you need a multi-dimensional array.  Simply a `double[,]` in your code.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried this, but Visual Studio's Object Browser showing me that it is System.Array type in function signature. And I can't pass simple multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you forgot to use a variable, Array current = new double[2, 2];

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. It's not complaying about type of variable now.